# How to make a buttons with colors of the rainbow in my cycle in html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

My project is made on jango framework.

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<div class="btngroup" role="group" aria-label="tags">
    <h3><a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{tag.title}}</a></h3>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

I will explain a little. In this cycle, I get link tags from the database, which I want to wrap in buttons of different colors of the rainbow. But how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HSL to easily create a color based on the item index and the total items in your array. H is for Hue, which is from 0 to 360. 0 is red, 120 is green, 240 is blue. You can simply calculate the percentage of 360 based on the index of the item in the loop.

So first, you need to create a filter because you won't be able to do calculations directly in a Django template. Create a folder named `templatetags` with two files inside: an empty `__init__.py` and `rainbow.py` with the following content:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def rainbow(i, array):
    return 360 * i / len(array)
```

Then, modify your code like this, so the background is changed with CSS, defining HSL colors. Make sure to include the filter:

```
{% load rainbow %}
{% for tag in tags %}
<div class="btngroup" role="group" aria-label="tags">
    <h3>
        <a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}" style="background:hsl({{ forloop.counter|rainbow:tags }},80%,50%)" class="btn btn-primary">{{tag.title}}</a>
    </h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

`forloop.counter` in Django will get the index of the current item in the loop. 80% is for S(saturation) and 50% for L(lightness). You might want to fine-tune this to match your design.

Live example: https://repl.it/repls/AbleOtherBytecode

Comment: Good day! Can you explain in more detail where to create this file with an array and whether it is necessary to specify it in applications ?

Comment: Hi, updated the answer with a live example and details how to create a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-image: linear-gradient on your .btngroup class. Set the height and width to what you prefer:

```css
.btngroup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet); 
  border-radius:4px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btngroup">Button<div>
```